# Get Size of every users .pst Files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Hey Guys I have to get the Size of every users `.pst` files in there directory. My problem is, I don't realy know how to make a `Foreach` which summs all `.pst` Files in a users directory. Don't laugh I know that the the foreach loop is completly wron xD

```
$arr = Get-ChildItem \\Server\users\z01 | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name} #Gets names of all Folders in this Directory

$Pfad = \\Server\users\z01\

foreach ($arr in $Pfad){
$Sum = Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Include *pst | measure Length -sum
}
 $Sum
```

Comment: Yeah it did work but I'm not completly finished yet.
`$Gesamt = Get-ChildItem $Verzeichniss |Select-Object Name,@{Name='TotalSizeInGB';Expression={ (Get-ChildItem -Path $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Archiv\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Outlook\ -Filter *$($FileType) | Measure Length -Sum).Sum /1.GB}}  | Sort-Object -Property TotalSizeInGB -Descending | Select-Object -Property Name,TotalSizeInGB -First 30`
It gets me all Names of the users and there Size in GB but I want to not have a 10 digit long nummber. It should only be maybe 2 digits long after the ".".

Comment: I have edited my answer and added code to do what I think you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest first getting an array of objects in which the pst files FullName and its'Length is kept. That way you can also export this info to a CSV file for further analysis.

Then use that array to calculate the total size:

```
$Pfad = '\\Server\users\z01'
# leave out -Recurse if you do NOT want to include files in subdirectories
$allPstFiles = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Pfad -Filter '*.pst' -File -Recurse | Select-Object FullName, Length
# you can output this on screen or write it to disk as Csv file, see 
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv

# next get the sum of all sizes
$totalSize = ($allPstFiles | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum

$totalSize
```

---

As per your latest comment, I understand that you want to have the sum of all *.pst files per user
(==> folder name inside `$Verzeichniss`), formatted in GB with only two digits after the decimal point.

In that case, try:

```
$Verzeichniss = '\\Server\users\z01'
$userFolders  = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Verzeichniss -Directory

$Gesamt = foreach ($dir in $userFolders) {
    # take the username from the folder name
    $userName = $dir.Name
    # find all *.pst files for this user
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir.FullName -Filter '*.pst' -File -Recurse | 
    # group them by a common property, in this case they all have .pst extension
    Group-Object {$_.Extension} | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = { $userName }},
                  @{Name = 'TotalSizeInGB'; Expression = { '{0:F2}' -f (($_.Group | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1Gb ) }}
} 

$Gesamt | Sort-Object -Property TotalSizeInGB -Descending | Select-Object -First 30
```

Answer (score 0):

So just to show what my final code was, I'll post it here. I hope you don't mind that the comments are in german ;) I think the code will speak for itself.

```
#Dieses Script Sucht nach dem geforderten Filetype in dem angegebenen Verzeichniss. Danach wird noch in dem gewünschten Verzeichniss ein CSV File erstellt welches
#alle Order und die summierte Grösse aller Files mit dem angegebenen Filetype anzeigt.

#Variabeln abspeichern

#Hier wird jeweils abgefragt nach welchem File Typ man filtern möchte.
$FileType = Read-Host "Nach welchem File Typ möchtest du suchen?"
#Falls die Eingabe nicht mit einem "." Beginnt wird der Variabel ein Punkt hinzugefügt.
if ($FileType.StartsWith -eq "."){

}else{
        $FileType = ".$($filetype)" 
}

#Für die nächstenbeiden Abfragen wird das gleiche Prinzip wie oben verwendet, einfach mit "\" für die Pfade.
$Verzeichniss = Read-Host "In welchem Verzeichniss möchtest du suchen?"
if ($Verzeichniss.EndsWith -eq "\"){

}else{
        $Verzeichniss += "\"
}

$CSV = Read-Host "Wo möchtest du das CSV File abspeichern?"
if ($CSV.EndsWith -eq "\"){

}else{
        $CSV += "\"
}

#Das Datum wird abgespeichrt um später im CSV Filename einen Timestamp hinzu zu fügen.
$date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd-hh-mm-ss"

#Hier wird ausgelesen mit welchem Zeichen Nummern getrent werden. Wird später gebraucht.
$Separator = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

#Script

#Hier wird für alle Ordner der Name abgespeichert. Zu dem wird die Grösse aller Files mit dem gewünschtem Filetyp im gleichen Array abgespeichert. Danach werden die Einträge nach der "TotalSizeInGB" Sortiert (Grösste oben). Am schluss werden dann nur noch die ersten 30 Einträge angezeigt.
$Gesamt = Get-ChildItem $Verzeichniss |Select-Object Name,@{Name='TotalSizeInGB';Expression={[math]::Round(((Get-ChildItem -Path $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\  -Filter *$($FileType) -Recurse -Force | Measure Length -Sum).Sum /1.GB),2)}}  | Sort-Object -Property TotalSizeInGB -Descending | Select-Object -Property Name,TotalSizeInGB -First 30

#Falls der Seperator ein "," ist, werden hier alle "," mit "." ersetzt.
if ($Separator = ","){
    $Gesamt = ($Gesamt | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String) -replace ',', '.'
}

#Am Ende wird hier noch das Verzeichniss nach welchem gesucht wird hinzugefügt, um Nachvollziehen zu können von wo die Einräge kommen.
$Gesamt += $Verzeichniss

#Als CSV abspeichern

#Die Variabel wird in einem csv abgespeichert.
$Gesamt | Out-File "$($CSV)temp.csv" -Encoding utf8
#Der Content des CSV wird in einer Variabel abgespeichert.
$import = get-content "$($CSV)temp.csv"
#Es wird eine Linie in der Variabel gescript und dan als CSV an dem gewünschten ort mit dem Timestamp abgespeichert.
$import | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File "$($CSV)list_$($date).csv"
#Das Alte CSV wird gelöscht.
Remove-Item "$($CSV)temp.csv"
```