# Replace all commas in a array with dots

Tags: powershell

I have a Array with this output:

```
Names       TotalSizeInGB
-----       ----
User1       17,4
User2       9,81
```

Does anybody know how I can can make all the numbers with a comma (17,4 and 9,81) to nummbers with dots (17.4 and 9.81)

Comment: Is the `TotalSizeInGB` property a string? (see `$array[0].TotalSizeInGB.GetType()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65843974/9898643), you can change the line

```
@{Name = 'TotalSizeInGB'; Expression = { '{0:F2}' -f (($_.Group | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1Gb ) }}
```

to

```
@{Name = 'TotalSizeInGB'; Expression = { [double](($_.Group | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1Gb ).ToString("F2", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture) }}
```

to get the numbers as **numeric values** (with a decimal point instead of a comma)

Otherwise, you can alter this afterwards and change the commas to get real numeric values from them using

```
foreach ($item in $array) {
    $item.TotalSizeInGB = [double]($item.TotalSizeInGB -replace ',', '.')
}
```

However, displaying this in your current locale (which uses a decimal comma, same as mine) will show they now **are** numbers (right-aligned), but automatically will display with a decimal comma:

```
Name  TotalSizeInGB
----  -------------
User1          17,4
User2          9,81
```

If you however export to CSV file, you'll see they have decimal points:

```
"Name","TotalSizeInGB"
"User1","17.4"
"User2","9.81"
```

If display in the console is all you're after, then simply leave out the cast to `[double]`. (this makes the values **strings**)

---

**To clarify:**

Use the first code for working with the numbers as numeric values (so having a dot as decimal point) in your script.
If you also want to ***display*** the table in the console where the numbers have decimal **points**, you need to replace the visual output, because if you don't, numbers are displayed with the machines `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` character, which in your case is the comma, not a dot.

For DISPLAYING the table with dots, you can do:

```
($Gesamt | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String) -replace ',', '.'
```

Again, this is for console output only. Nothing in the `$Gesamt` array is actually changed.

Comment: Yeah I did the first answer that you gave and it worked. But the Problem is. I make a sort-object later on on "TotalSizeInGB" and then it reads it as a string so that its sortet like
5.10
4.10
31.25
3.19
2.06
11.23

Is there a way to leave the nummbers in Int and not make them into a string?

Comment: @Forestbird I have added a cast to `[double]` in the first answer now. This makes for real numbers you can sort on

Comment: Hey I added The '[double]' but now it does not do anything. its still with commas

Comment: @Forestbird. That is unfortunately how it _displays_ in the console, because there it uses the current machine's cultureinfo to display numbers with decimals. You can check this if you run `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` where it will show a comma. If you do `$Gesamt |  Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\The\Gesamt.csv' -NoTypeInformation` and look in there, you will see the comma's in the numbers in fact are dots. Since you are using these numbers to sort on, you MUST have them with decimal dots, otherwise the script will treat them as strings.

Comment: @Forestbird Please see my edit to the question which will hopefully explain

Comment: can you please explain me how the thin with the `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` works. Cause on one PC it works that after that everywhere are dots and on the other there are still commas...

Comment: @Forestbird `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` just shows you what the Windows language settings are and if the system uses a dot or a comma as decimal character. If one machine is in us-ENG for instance, it will show a dot. If another machine is set to using German or Dutch, it wil show a comma.

Comment: @Forestbird Also keep in mind that `($Gesamt | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String) -replace ',', '.'` is for console output ONLY. Nothing in the $Gesamt array gets changed. It simply produces a string where all commas are replaced by dots. If after this you still output `$Gesamt | Format-Table` it will display commas again on your machine, because it uses German language settings.

Comment: Okay seems like that its the only way to save the nummbers in a string. But thats fine. Thank you very much @Theo for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

for each iteration use the below line :

`$string` contains a line

> $string = $string -replace '.', ''

Comment: Before proceeding further convert that value in string and try this one :                      
PS C:\> $demo = "12.6"
PS C:\> $demo.replace('.',',')